# What are effective techniques to break down TDD from a business level to the unit level?

Tags: tdd, bdd

I totally get TDD at a low level but I see very little information in actually applying these techniques to a large, complex project. Applying it to a single function/class is easy, but when I have to think about hundreds of components interacting with each other, I am a bit lost.

Currently I am writing user stories, then building features and scenarios but that's as far as I have gotten.

- How can I know if I'm writing good user stories (aren't too broad, aren't irrelevant)?
- Is it good practice to use BDD on top of TDD?
- If so do I still follow the TDD flow where I write a scenario (which is essentially an integration test in my case), and then let that fail until every unit test is passing underneath it?
- If not what are effective techniques to break down the testing from a business level to the unit level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For user stories, you might want to read the books by Gojko Adzik, expecially [Fifty Quick Ideas To Improve User Stories](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OGT2U7M).

Yes, it is smart to use BDD as the "outer loop" of TDD.

One way of doing it is the one you outlined.  You might want to read [Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/), which gives you a much in-depth description of the process of going from high-level end-to-end tests to granular unit tests.

Another way to learn is to look at [the first video from Sandro Mancuso and Uncle Bob in the series](https://cleancoders.com/episode/comparativeDesign-episode-1/show) where they compare the so-called London and Detroit schools of TDD.

Comment: Just downloaded a sample of Growing OO Software by Tests and the intro seems like it will be a great fit for answering my questions. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: Just a small update, read most of the book suggested and it answered the majority of my questions. Top down TDD is a fantastic testing methodology. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you liked it Ryall!  Happy coding!